# Does Apache look at .htaccess files above a VirtualHost's DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, .htaccess, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a subdomain on a server of mine, where `blog.domain.com` serves the content from `domain.com/blog/`

Perhaps this is the wrong way of doing this entirely, but I have setup a `blog.domain.com` `VirtualHost` for this, whose `DocumentRoot` is `/path-to-domain.com-root/blog/`. However, it seems that the .htaccess file from the original `DocumentRoot` (i.e. `/path-to-domain.com-root/.htaccess`) is still being applied even under the new subdomain's `VirtualHost`.

So, I'm wondering, does Apache look at .htaccess files, even if they're above the `DocumentRoot` — if so, how can I stop it from doing this (it's rewriting the URL and sending it to somewhere that I don't want it to go)? Or if there's a better way of doing this, I accept that I might be being a complete idiot and doing it totally wrong :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you look at the [.htaccess files tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html) in the Apache documentation to get an idea of how they are applied.

Basically Apache will walk up the directory tree looking for htaccess files unless you have an `AllowOverride None` directive in a `<Directory>` statement.

**Edit:**
Apache will keep going till it hits an `AllowOverride None` directive for a directory. Most servers come configured with it set for `/` and whatever the default server root is. This keeps the default configuration from traversing past your web root. However, the default is also `None`, so I think this must be for clarification purposes only. I suggest you check your default `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file to be sure.

Comment: I did see that, but it doesn't mention where (or if) it stops… will it traverse right up to the root directory?

Comment: …by which I mean /, not the `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Added some clarification regarding the traversal.